# How to update configurable product description using sku via script in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.2

How to update configurable product description using sku via script?? I have used below code for config product, It is failed to function properly for configurable product. Please suggest me a solution

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', '5');

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo 'hi';
    $product->setData('short_description', 'It is a good cloth to wear');
    $product->save();
    echo "Product Updated" . " ";
}
```

Comment: have you check using     $product->setData('description', 'It is a good cloth to wear');

Comment: yes it is properly working for simple product

Comment: I need to update description for a configurable product using sku. In above code I have put configurable product's sku id. But it was not working properly. Beacause Associative products contains different sku id. So Please guide me where i have to modify a code?

Comment: your sku for product is 3?

Comment: Pant is a Configurable product whose sku  is 5 . Associative products are Pant-green and Pant-Yellow whose sku are  5-green and 5-Yellow.

Comment: you need to set description instead of short_description in above code at line, $product->setData('short_description', 'It is a good cloth to wear');

Comment: If i give sku as 5 then how it will be respond for associative products Because each product contains different sku

Comment: you need to give each time exact sku match with product.

Comment: Yes i have changed as u said but now the code hides the product from frontview

Comment: But product present in admin panel

Comment: Control unable to enter into foreach loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67626/discussion-between-jayashree-and-rakesh).